# Expression... LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types”

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have this generic method:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> PaginateAndOrderByDesc<TEntity>(int pageIndex, int pageSize, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> orderByDescending)
        where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
    {
        int numberOfRecordsToSkip = (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize;

        return context.Set<TEntity>().OrderByDescending(orderByDescending).Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip).Take(pageSize);
    }
```

When I use it:

```
List<Person> people = repository.PaginateAndOrderByDesc<Person>(1,
            30, x = > x.RegistrDate)
            .ToList();
```

I get an error: "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

How do I make that Generic function work with orderByDescending expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a generic argument to represent the type you are ordering on:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> PaginateAndOrderByDesc<TEntity, TKey>(
    int pageIndex, 
    int pageSize,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>> sortSelector)
where TEntity : class, IContextEntity
{
    int numberOfRecordsToSkip = (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize;

    return context.Set<TEntity>()
        .OrderByDescending(sortSelector)
        .Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip)
        .Take(pageSize);
}
```

Having said that, I would suggest not including the `OrderBy` method within this query.  It reduces the readability of your query to combine the "order the data" and "get a certain page" operations.  Keep them separate.  The "order the data" operation is just fine as it is; you really only need to create a "get a certain page" query:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetPage<TEntity>(
    this IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> query,
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize)
{
    int numberOfRecordsToSkip = (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize;

    return query.Skip(numberOfRecordsToSkip)
        .Take(pageSize);
}
```

In addition to giving you greater power to compose your queries as you see fit, this more importantly results in more readable queries in which what is happening is very clear based on the methods called.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! I searched half of the internet and could not find right solution for this. And you're right about keeping it simple!

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to mention doing JUST the GetPage operation.  I always tell myself (and other devs) anytime you use the word "And" or "Or" in your method signature, rethink what you're doing and why you are using a conditional phrase in a signature.  If you're using a conditional phrase, why aren't they separate operations?